# Is there a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f\big(\cap_{i\in I} A_i) \neq \cap_{i\in I}f\big(A_i)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Is there a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $$f\big(\cap_{i\in I} A_i) \neq \cap_{i\in I}f\big(A_i)$$

Where $A_i\subseteq X$ and $I$ is an arbitrary index set.

I can easily find a discontinuous function, for example $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$ and $f(x) =x$ otherwise. Then taking subsets $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ works.

However I am struggling to find a continous $f$. Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f$ constant, let $A_i\neq\varnothing$ for each $i\in I$ and let $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^2$; $A_1=\{-1\}$; $A_2=\{1\}$.

$g(x)=0$; $A_i=\{i\}$, $i\in\mathbb R$.